# javascript parentNode is undefined

Tags: javascript, dom, parent, parent-node

Here is my HTML markup -

```
<div>
  <div class="my_class">
   // some code goes here...
  </div>
</div>
```

And when I try to get parent as follows, It returns undefined.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('my_class').parentNode  // returns undefined
```

I want to remove element having class 'my_class' as follows -

```
document.getElementsByClassName('my_class').parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementsByClassName('my_class'))
```

But I'm not able to access parentNode.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, not a single element.

Comment: try `getElementsByClassName("my_class")[0]`

Comment: @elclanrs Thanks man! document.getElementsByClassName('my_class')[0].parentNode did the trick.

Comment: @SuyashSoni Had you used a debugger or console.log, you could have seen that `getElementsByClassName` didn't return a single value.